# Jupyterlab: How to install specific version?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

How do you install a specific version of Jupyterlab?

I've looked around in [jupyterlab installations](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html) and [the changelog](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/changelog.html#v1-0-0) with no success. I've also tried various approaches with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab --version 1.0.0
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: `--version` shows conda version. Try @Dan answer or just use `pip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages):

> To install a specific version of a package such as SciPy:
>
> `conda install scipy=0.15.0`

So I would guess in your case try

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=1.0.0
```